# Create a vector that tracks the accumulation of new elements in a vector

Tags: r, loops, vector

I have a character vector (of numbers, letters and mixed values) and would like to create a vector of whether the element in the position `x` has been seen previously in the vector. If so, assign 0, else, assign 1. I would need it not just to be compared with the `x - 1` element, but with *all* the previous elements.

Stated differently, I like to see when a new element type arise (by the jump in the sum value).

**Data set sample**:

```
u
Q  Q  Q  F  F  F  M  F  F  M2 F  F  F  F  F  F  F  M2 F F  F  F  F  F  F  F  M  P  M  P  P  M  P  P  M  E  H  3
```

**Expected output**:

```
1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 7 7 7..
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Sorry, but your description does not fit your example of a desired outcome and the desired outcome does not coincide with the lengths of the runs of your data set. I have trouble understanding the pattern you are looking for (and Ian Campbell seems to have the same problem). Could you please clarify?

Comment: Hi! Thank you, I am obviously newbie, sorry for the lame explanation. The idea is to compare elements of the vector if they are equal or not, and if they are, the number of elements appearing would grow with each element. If the vector is u<- c("a",''a",''a","b","b","c", ''b'',''a''), I would like to get the outcome of : 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3.

Comment: Vector is column of the table, which is made of elements column and time stamp for each element column. I would need to plot so called "exhaustion-curve", plotting on y-axis the sum of new elements, and x-the time when new element appears in the data set

Comment: In that case, both answers will help you do the job. Take your pick.

Comment: @DivnaDjokic See if my edited answer is what you're looking for.

Comment: HI Ian, thank you so so much, worked like a charm, and totally did what I looked for! Thanks everyone for help!

Comment: one more question- is there a way to do the same thing but for the whole data frame, made of the same type of data? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit:

Based on your clarifications in the comments to @akrun's answer, see if this is what you're looking for:

```
sapply(seq_along(u), function(x) length(unique(u[1:x])))
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 7 8
```

**Sample Data**

```
u <- c("Q", "Q", "Q", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F", "M2", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M2", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "M", "P", "M", "P", "P", "M", "P", "P", "M", "E", "H", 
"3")
```

Comment: @akrun I just hope that's what the OP wanted, or I've made a mess of their question.

Comment: I think `lengths` would make it more efficient `lengths(lapply(seq_along(u), function(x) unique(u[seq_len(x)])))`

Comment: YOu can add it on yours.  It is just a simple change

Comment: @akrun Interestingly, the `lengths` version seems to be *slightly* slower. Maybe has to do with dispatch.

Answer (score 2):

We can also do this with `rleid`

```
library(data.table)
rleid(u)
```

---

Or with `rle` from `base R`

```
with(rle(u), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))
```

#### data

```
u <- c("Q", "Q", "Q", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F", "M2", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M2", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "M", "P", "M", "P", "P", "M", "P", "P", "M", "E", "H", 
"3")
```

Comment: Sorry, I obviously explained it badly. I would need it not just to be compared with the previous element, but with ALL the previous elements. I would basically need to see when a new element type arise (by the jump in the sum value). Hope it is a bit clearer now!

Comment: @DivnaDjokic sorry, I was looking at the other answer while coded.

Comment: @DivnaDjokic can you expand your descrpiton because `if the element in the position x = to the element in the position x+1, then assign 0, else, assign 1.` seems to be checking for adjacent elements

Comment: @DivnaDjokic Can you show the full expected output.  I guess `tibble(u) %>% group_by(grp = rleid(u)) %>% summarise(u1 = first(u), u = list(u)) %>% mutate(flag = cumsum(!duplicated(u1))) %>% unnest(c(u)) %>% pull(flag)` should work

Comment: @DivnaDjokic in your post, the input vector length is 38 and output vector length is 43.  So, it is not clear

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the following code works for you

```
> cumsum(!duplicated(u))
 [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 7 8
```